# Issue keeping items centered within floating divs

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a project, and thru various methods have managed to get text to sit carefully next to an image on the platform I am using. Both the image and the text are centered, but the text is left-justified.

The page should be responsive, and generally works well, however as the size of the browser shrinks, eventually the text is pushed to the next line, as it should be. Unfortunately, when this happens, it is no longer centered, and the image become off-centered.

I've been stuck for a while trying to figure out exactly what can be fixed within my current theme/use case - and would love any suggestions.
https://jsfiddle.net/xLwy83rj/

```
<div style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; min-width: 250px;">
<!--I edit the margins in the next block to better prevent the text from flowing over the bottom of the image if its a smaller or larger block of text -->
<img style="float: left; margin-right: 1rem; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/128x128" />
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block; width: 200px;">
<p style="text-align: left;"><strong>Attack Gloves</strong><br />
Base DPS: ~<strong>572.5</strong><br />
Attack Range: <strong>1100</strong><br />
Heat Buildup: <strong>95</strong><br />
Heat Buildup: <strong>95</strong><br />
Heat Buildup: <strong>95</strong><br />
Heat Buildup: <strong>95</strong></p>
```

Specifically the goal is to keep the 2 main elements centered at all times, with just a bit of space between them. If the browser is too small to display them side-by-side, it pushes the text down below, and keeps everything centered still.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: which items you want to keep centered all time?

Comment: @RobertWilliamsthe jsfiddle is in the post.

Comment: @OptimumCreative both the image and the block of text should be centered at all times, the text should remain left justified within its div, but the entire div of text should be centered (if that makes sense)

Comment: see answer below.. i am adding now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo used flex](https://jsfiddle.net/ws29tcx8/)

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.p{
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="top">
<img class="alignnone second" src="http://via.placeholder.com/128x128" />
</div>

<div class="third">   
    <p class="p"><strong>Attack Gloves</strong><br />
    Base DPS: ~<strong>572.5</strong><br />
    Attack Range: <strong>1100</strong><br />
    Heat Buildup: <strong>95</strong><br />
    Heat Buildup: <strong>95</strong><br />
    Heat Buildup: <strong>95</strong><br />
    Heat Buildup: <strong>95</strong></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Close, but the content sits left of middle after wrapping. After wrapping, the text sits under the image, but neither readjust their position for the fact that there is no text on the above line.

edit: for what it's worth, this is the closest I managed to get as well, and the closest of any shot so far!

Comment: The newest iteration using flex now works! Thank you so much, and now off I go to read more about this so I can understand it better in the future! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML

HTML

```
<div style="text-align:center;width:50%;margin:auto;">
<!--I edit the margins in the next block to better prevent the text from flowing over the bottom of the image if its a smaller or larger block of text -->
<img class="alignnone" src="http://via.placeholder.com/128x128" style="display:inline-block;" />
<p style="display:inline-block;"><strong>Attack Gloves</strong><br />
Base DPS: ~<strong>572.5</strong><br />
Attack Range: <strong>1100</strong><br />
Heat Buildup: <strong>95</strong><br />
Heat Buildup: <strong>95</strong><br />
Heat Buildup: <strong>95</strong><br />
Heat Buildup: <strong>95</strong></p>
</div>
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/xLwy83rj/2/)

changed a bit

Comment: On this one, the text just sits under the image at all times, rather than staying to the right of it unless there is not enough space. Also, once it wraps, each line of text is centered, rather than the div/block of text (though this is not really a huge part of the problem)

Comment: remove width on the main div and give a try

Comment: Still sitting vertical - in the visual preview it actually shows it side-by-side, and that is actually a smaller window - playing with it now to see if I can come up with any reason >.>

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; min-width: 250px; text-align:center; float:left;">
<!--I edit the margins in the next block to better prevent the text from flowing over the bottom of the image if its a smaller or larger block of text -->
<img class="alignnone" style="display:inline-blcok; margin-right: 1rem; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;" src="http://via.placeholder.com/128x128" />

</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; float:left;">
<p style="text-align: left;"><strong>Attack Gloves</strong><br />
Base DPS: ~<strong>572.5</strong><br />
Attack Range: <strong>1100</strong><br />
Heat Buildup: <strong>95</strong><br />
Heat Buildup: <strong>95</strong><br />
Heat Buildup: <strong>95</strong><br />
Heat Buildup: <strong>95</strong></p>

</div>
```

Comment: On this one, the image is centered at all times within its boundry, but the goal is to keep it next to the text, unless the text is not there. In addition, the text is left align after wrapping

Comment: You will need to use proper classes and media queries  to handle this at different screen sized. please create a proper code with classes and write css media query to handle at different screen sizes.